# Is there a faster way to compute element wise exponentials of a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, performance

I am profiling my code and this one line seems to be a bottleneck. The idea is to create a spatial correlation matrix of n observations of a given dimension, based upon a theta vector of the same dimension--which contains dimensional hyperparameters to be fit.

In my overall code this spatial correlation function is called thousands of times (per iteration) while computing a likelihood function in order to optimize my theta parameters. The number of observations grows by one in each iteration of the overall code, and the theta parameters must be refit each iteration. So you can see how this line of code becomes crucial as the algorithm progresses.

I think that the slowest line, i.e., `R = exp(sum(bsxfun(@times, -abs(D_X).^corr_model,reshape(theta,[1 1 d])),3));` takes the most time to compute the final element-wise exponential across the resulting n by n matrix (the n by n matrix is yielded after summing over the 3 dimension of the distance matrix). But there is a lot going on in this line, so I am unsure if this is the most critical aspect to the overall performance.

Thanks for any insight you may have!

I have already replaced a `repmat` command with a `bsxfun`, to multiply the given thetas across the dimensional distance matrix `D_X`, which sped up the code notably. However, nesting a second `bsxfun` to execute the squaring of distances i.e., to replace `abs(D_X).^corr_model`, made the code run slower.

```
n = 500;
dimension = 20;
D_X = repmat(rand(n),[1 1 dimension]);
theta = rand(dimension, 1);
corr_model = 2;

R = corr(corr_model,theta, D_X);

function R = corr(corr_model,theta,D_X)
% calculate the correlation matrix for the modified nugget effect model
% corr_model - the correlation model used for the spatial correlation
% corr_model = 2: gaussian correlation function
% theta - vector of hyperparameters
% D_X - the distance matrix for the input locations

d = size(theta,1);

switch corr_model
    case 2 %Gaussian correlation function  
        R = exp(sum(bsxfun(@times, -abs(D_X).^corr_model,reshape(theta,[1 1 d])),3));
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more optimized version:

```
n = 500;
dimension = 20;
D_X = rand(n);
theta = rand(dimension, 1);
corr_model = 2;

function R = corr(corr_model, theta, D_X)
    switch corr_model
        case 2  
            R = exp(-sum(theta)) .^ ( D_X .^ corr_model );
    end
end
```

These steps have been taken:

```
R = exp(sum(bsxfun(@times, -abs(D_X).^corr_model,reshape(theta,[1 1 d])),3));
R = exp((-abs(D_X) .^ corr_model) .* sum(theta)) ;
R = exp((-D_X .^ corr_model) .* sum(theta)) ;
R = exp((D_X .^ corr_model) .* (-sum(theta)));
R = exp(-sum(theta)) .^ ( D_X .^ corr_model );
```

- Instead of `repmat` you can just set `D_X = rand(n)` so you can factor out `(-abs(D_X) .^ corr_model)` and multiply it be sum of `theta`.
- Since `D_X` is a real matrix `abs(D_X)^2` is equivalent to `D_X^2`.
- Converting `(-D_X.^corr_model) .*sum(theta)` to `(D_X.^corr_model) .*(-sum(theta))` may speedup the computation because you only negate a scalar that should be more cheaper than negating an array.
- Knowing that `x^(ab) = (x^a)^b` the expression  `exp(( D_X .^ corr_model ) .* (-sum(theta)))` can be converted to `exp(-sum(theta)) .^ ( D_X .^ corr_model )`. In the first expression we have three operations on `D_X` but in the second expression two operations are applied on `D_X`.

## EDIT:

As noted in the comment slices of the `D_X` matrix are different so the above method isn't applicable so you can use the following method:

```
D_X1 = reshape(permute(D_X, [3 2 1]), dimension,[]);
%calling thousands of times
for k = 1 : 10000
    R = corr(corr_model,theta, D_X1);
end
% matrix reshaped to its original size
Result = reshape(R,n,n);

function R = corr(corr_model, theta, D_X)
    switch corr_model
        case 2  
            R = exp(-theta.' * (D_X.^corr_model));
    end
end
```

Here  `D_X` is permutated and reshaped to a `[20 x 250000]` matrix so instead of sum of products you can use matrix multiplication.
Also if the correlation matrix is symmetric you can use half of its elements. Now the matrix size is `[20 x 125250]`.

```
idx = tril(true(n));
D_X1 = reshape(permute(D_X, [3 2 1]), dimension,[]);
D_X1 = D_X1(:,idx);

for k = 1 : 10000
    R = corr(corr_model,theta, D_X1);
end

% matrix reshaped to its original size
Result = zeros(n);
Result(idx) = R;
d = diag(Result);
Result = Result + Result.'
Result(1:n+1:end)=d;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to look at this. But I don't believe that this will work since my D_X is a 3 dimensional matrix/tensor. I needed to do the repmat just so that I could get something that was 500x500x20, and thus resembles something similar to my actual distance matrix/tensor.

In essence I have 500 samples in 20 dimensions, and I need to find the distance between each pair of samples- in each dimension. Then I need to multiply those dimensional distances by the respective theta parameter. So I don't think that the math works out to sum over theta first?

Comment: It would be better to rewrite your example as `D_X = rand(n,n,dimension);` to show you have 20 different correlation matrices but your current example shows that you only have one correlation matrix. Answer updated.